# Apache2 httpd proxy to Tomcat: how to tell Tomcat it is secure connection?

Tags: tomcat, https, apache2, reverse-proxy, tomcat9

Apache2 httpd proxy to Tomcat: how to tell Tomcat it is secure connection?

```
client -- https --- Apache2 Httpd ---http-- Tomcat
```

From httpd to Tomcat: use http.

```
            ProxyPreserveHost On


            ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
            ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

But a webapp in Tomcat requires the connection must be secure by calling

```
request.isSecure()
```

Is there a directive in Httpd configuration to tell Tomcat it is secure?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this on the Tomcat side - but make sure that you're actually *only* proxying TLS-traffic to your Tomcat: Look up the `secure` attribute (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> secure) in tomcat's [Connector documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html), where it says:

> Set this attribute to true if you wish to have calls to `request.isSecure()` to return `true` for requests received by this Connector. You would want this on an SSL Connector or a non SSL connector that is receiving data from a SSL accelerator, like a crypto card, an SSL appliance or even a webserver. The default value is `false`.